# GWT Material. Add InlineSearch in table header

Tags: java, xml, gwt, gwt-material-design

How can i add this search icon

```
<m:MaterialLink iconType="SEARCH" ui:field="openSearch" iconColor="BLACK" float="RIGHT"/>
```

and this Inline search

```
<incubator:search.ExpandableInlineSearch ui:field="txtSearch" theme="LIGHT" width="50%" placeholder="Search" display="INLINE"/>
```

in header of material table?

```
<mt:MaterialDataTable addStyleNames="{style.text-wrap}" ui:field="table"
                                           height="calc(100vh - 151px)"
                                           useStickyHeader="false"
                                           useCategories="false"
                                           useRowExpansion="false"
                                           selectionType="NONE"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, finally! That was so easy.

You should use this:

```
@UiField
MaterialDataTable<MailNotificationDTO> table;

Panel panel = table.getScaffolding().getToolPanel();
panel.add(new MaterialIcon(IconType.SEARCH));'
```

And the same for inline search